# Line by Line Source Control Indicator Plugin for Visual Studio

Tags: windows, software-development, visual-studio

I am looking for a plugin for Visual Studio that would give me the indicator functionality similar to that of [GitGutter](https://github.com/jisaacks/GitGutter) for Sublime Text. I'd like it to work with SVN (or better yet agnostic to the version control system).  Preferably gratis, but I don't mind paying a little.

Basically I want to be able to quickly see which lines were added, modified, and deleted since the last commit.

Visual Studio already provides great functionality to see changes since opening the file, but I need it to be since the last commit.

This is a sample image from GitGutter's GitHub page:
[image: GitGutter screenshot]

The green plus sign indicates that the line was added since the last commit.  The purple square indicates that the line was modified.  The red triangle indicates a line was deleted.

Answer (score 3):

Would it happen to be something like [VisualSVN for Visual Studio](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/DBD60715-FE57-44B5-ABEA-F18618068C1E)? I remember using it before I made the switch to git, and VS2012. It can be free, [depending on usage](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/purchase/). There's also one for [git](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/63a7e40d-4d71-4fbb-a23b-d262124b8f4c), if you prefer.

Unfortunately, there really doesn't seem to be an agnostic solution, as having a source integrator dealing with two different repository types could be quite cumbersome...

Comment: Please include in the body of the answer at least the name of the product, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should try this extension, it satisfies your expectation https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LaurentKempe.GitDiffMargin

Comment: Could you please explain why it satisfies expectation?  That would make a much better answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).